# trying to split up a mesh with segments of the exact same volume

Tags: mesh

I want to split up my mesh in segments of the same volume, not mass or area but volume. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this. I already tried using the fracture modifier but I can't seem to get it right despite using a lot of different settings.

Here is a picture of what I already tried but not getting the result I'm looking for.
[image: segmented object in blender]

Some extra information, my mesh's volume is 181000 m<sup>3</sup> and I want to divide it in 1200 segments of 152 m<sup>3</sup> each.

Comment: Is it a general case question or is it for a particular model?

Comment: let's say for simplicity it's an oblongated sphere. and i want to cut it up along a specific axis in segments like they become discs. but i want the discs to be the exact same volume of one another.

Comment: Should the calculation keep the mesh vertices (so approx the volume) or add cuts to the mesh?

Comment: i want to add cuts to the mesh so i get segments based on volume so i can calculate the distance required between each segment line.

Comment: Hi bart, have you solved what you expect? I've tried on my side and have some results but nothing "perfect". Any feedback may be good.